# macOS terminal doesn't create files in right directory

Tags: python, django, macos, terminal, pipenv

I wanted to use virtual Django environment with pipenv. I created a file named djangotest in my desktop. I accessed it in terminal using `cd ~/Desktop/djangotest`

then I ran `pipenv install django`
and it says it installed successfully.

I opened the djangotest folder and didn't see pipfile and pipfile.lock . Then I saw that pipfile and pipfile.lock was created on my Desktop instead of the directory I wanted them to install on.

So is there a problem here or is it the thing that was supposed to happen?

Comment: Do you mean "I created a **folder** named djangotest"?

Answer (score 0):

pipenv is intended to create the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` in the current working directory. So instead of creating a "file" named djangotest, create a directory.

```
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir djangotest
cd djangotest
pipenv install django
```